# Span rows with RowHeader

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hope someone can point me in the right direction in accomplishing this.
Trying to group rows of a data bound DataGridView in winform c# application, and have the row header span across the group. I have the DataGridView grouping and displaying the results, but not having any luck getting the row header to span. Tried this link [How to Merge DataGridView Cell in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms) but couldn’t get it adapt to what I need.

[image]

Comment: The link only shows how to get rid of the separating borders, it doesn't show how to merge the cells because it isn't possible with `DataGridViews`. If that's not good enough you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/bbda3e63-30f2-47f1-ae00-2f022796c21e/merge-datagridview-row-and-column-cells) page might help you. You can do this by handling the cellPaint event.