# How to bind a List<T> to a DataGridView cell

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a list of `Foo` that is bound to a DataGridView. One of the members of `Foo` is a `List<Bar> Bars`, where `Bar` is an enum:

```
public class Foo { 
    public string Field1 {get;} 
    public List<Bar> Bars {get;} 
}
```

How can I display all items of `Bars` inside a single cell for each row? E.g., if I have a single `Foo` with `Field1 = "Blah";` and `Bars = new List<Bar>{ Bars.BarV1, Bars.BarV2};` I need the grid to look like that:

```
+------+----------+
|Field1|   Bars   |
+------+----------+
|      | BarV1 [v]|
| Blah +----------+
|      | BarV2 [v]|
+------+----------+
```

Will my task be simplified if I switch to WPF?

Answer (score 0):

There are two good examples for you. That [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms) is very similar to yours and check [that](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10d8b618-021b-41d7-8fa5-bfe22e9b94f8/how-can-i-split-datagridview-cell-data-in-c?forum=winformsdatacontrols) also.