# How do I put a combobox into 2 columns of the header in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I would like to add a Combobox at the position indicated in the image:

[image]

Any ideas, any tips on these will be great help!

Comment: share your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms this might get you hint of merging cells..