# Custom cell merged

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, merge, devexpress

I need to display data in gridview with merged rows for some columns.
the original data from database like:

[image]

please help me to display gridview like:

[image]

- for column **transaksi** merged by **tgl**
- for column **priority** , **price** , **creted by** merged by **transaksi**

Using C#, how can I prepare a gridview for the format? Please help me.

Comment: https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114730/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Getting-Started/Walkthroughs/Grid-View-Columns-Rows-and-Cells/Tutorial-Cell-Merging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go through documentation - [Tutorial: Cell Merging](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114730/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Getting-Started/Walkthroughs/Grid-View-Columns-Rows-and-Cells/Tutorial-Cell-Merging)

> To implement custom cell merge use the [GridView.CellMerge](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CellMerge.event) event
>   handler. First, check if the correct column is being processed. Then,
>   obtain display texts for the two cells being compared. Finally,
>   indicate that cells are to be merged if their display texts match. Set
>   the [CellMergeEventArgs.Handled](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CellMergeEventArgs.Handled.property) parameter to true to override the
>   grid's default processing for this column.

**Example:**

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
// ... 
private void gridView1_CellMerge(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CellMergeEventArgs e) {
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    if(view == null) return;
    if (e.Column == colCreatorID) {
        string text1 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle1, colCreatorID);
        string text2 = view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle2, colCreatorID);
        e.Merge = (text1 == text2);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Use your own conditions while processing a column. for example take `transaksi 005`, In this case check values of row 5 and 6 then compare column created by for equality depends upon your condition set the `e.Merge` to `true`.

Comment: I've used this step, but I still do not understand to apply with my case. can you help me to get more detail with my case.

Comment: thank you I understand what you mean. I've found the answer by comparing two columns based on group merge.

Answer (score 1):

I just picked response posted on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms) and added one line to achieve what you want.

```cs
bool IsTheSameCellValue(int column, int row)
{
    // To compare only values on 1st and 2nd column (TGL, TRANSAKSI)
    if (column > 1) return false;

    DataGridViewCell cell1 = dataGridView[column, row];
    DataGridViewCell cell2 = dataGridView[column, row - 1];
    if (cell1.Value == null || cell2.Value == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return cell1.Value.ToString() == cell2.Value.ToString();
}

private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
    if (e.RowIndex < 1 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;
    if (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
    {
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
    }
    else
    {
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = dataGridView.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top;
    }
}

private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == 0)
        return;
    if (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
    {
        e.Value = "";
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

However it's impossible to center text vertically in merged cells with this solution because it only erases the borders and not totally redraw the component.

Comment: thanks for answer my question, but i don't see event CellFormatting and CellPainting in my GridView.. i'm using GridView DexExpress..