# How can I create row groups by ID and separate the groups in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am currently receiving a list of objects and this list goes right into my DataGridView.
I would like to group my rows by ID, separating other groups by a big border.
For example:
1
simple border
1
Big border
2
simple border
2
simple border
2
However, I can't manage to modify only a row's upper/lower border.
I'm not very experienced, so I'd like to stay with "official" sources, avoiding plugins etc.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2012, and the language is C#.
I just looked at the row /cell properties and none can seem to fulfill my request.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_LectureEcritures.Rows)
{
    if (row.Index != 0)
    {
        //If ID is different from previous row
        if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value) != Convert.ToInt32(dgv_LectureEcritures.Rows[row.Index-1].Cells[0].Value))
          {
                //Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value) + " " + Convert.ToInt32(dgv_LectureEcritures.Rows[row.Index - 1].Cells[0].Value));
                //thicken upper border                
          }
     }
}
```

I thought I just had to modify here a property but since there is no property for what I want I don't quite know what to do.
Thanks for any help you can bring !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16774966/5045688

Comment: I'll check, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code, You may need to change according to your requirements

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex + 1 >= dataGridView1.RowCount)
            return;

        string currentValue = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex] == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string nextValue = dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex + 1] == null ? string.Empty : dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex + 1].Value.ToString();

        Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X,
           e.CellBounds.Y, e.CellBounds.Width,
           e.CellBounds.Height);

        using (
            Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.GridColor),
            backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor),
            foregroundBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor),
            boldBorderBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black)
            )
        {
            using (Pen normalGridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush),
                 boldGridLinePen = new Pen(boldBorderBrush, 2))
            {
                // Erase the cell.
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);

                if (!currentValue.Equals(nextValue))
                {
                    //Draw grid line on the bottom
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(boldGridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left,
                        e.CellBounds.Bottom, e.CellBounds.Right,
                        e.CellBounds.Bottom);
                }

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(normalGridLinePen, newRect);

                // Draw the text content of the cell, ignoring alignment.
                if (e.Value != null)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font,
                        foregroundBrush, e.CellBounds.X + 2,
                        e.CellBounds.Y + 2, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !