# How to merge columns in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

This is the datagridview that I have [current dgview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA5Lo.png)

But I want to merge columns in the gridview so it looks like in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

My code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    dgc[i] = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    dgc[i].HeaderText = row["account_name"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgc[i]);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: i dynamically generate columns with the value from database  database like above code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16774966/5045688