# Transition from a DataGridView to an ObjectListView to display image from database and merge rows

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, objectlistview

I hope someone can help with this Transition from a DataGridView to an ObjectListView.

The ObjectListView was suggested as a better solution to an earlier post [see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355319/how-to-merge-datagridview-cells-based-on-same-id-column-0)

I currently utilise an sql query to return a list of strings and an byte[] Image.

This successfully populates my DataGridView using DataSource.

My first issue is I am unable to get the images to display in the image column when I utilise the ObjectListView.SetObjects().

If I change the returned list from the query to return a Bitmap rather than the byte[]  the image column displays “System.Drawing.Bitmap”

My other issue is I would like my final ObjectListView to merge Rows form Column 0 to Column X where the ID in Column 0 are the same.

Thus providing me with results similar to those in my earlier post [see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355319/how-to-merge-datagridview-cells-based-on-same-id-column-0).

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Update

I stupidly forgot to include the ImageRenderer that is why the images were not displaying.

This has posed a new question how to restrict the image size to that of the cell?

Comment: Merging rows with a DGV is very difficult.  Better to use a custom listview like this codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate merging rows with DGV is very difficult that is why I am asking how this can be achieved utilising the ObjectListView

Comment: The code project is a ListView.  There is complete source code at the link that you can use for reference or use the entire library that is posted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been working through the samples and the reference documentation for this objectListView with absolutely no success when it comes to Merging Rows. I was hoping someone would be able to provide a specific code example or reference to one that would achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: You don't merge rows.  Each listview row is an object (with multiple controls). You want to add an object on your value column that can contain more than one row.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on what I need to be doing but I am still struggling with this. Is there any sample code you can point me to that deals with this specific  issue?

Comment: The CodeProject first download has sample code.  You will need a for loop when value has more than one row so you can add more than one row in the value column.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance but despite my efforts I am still unable to figure out how to get this to work. ListViews are new to me and I believe need to understand better how they work.