# is it possible to show 2 values in DataGridView? like tables in html for example 'rowspan'?

Tags: c#, vb.net

is there any possibility to make DataGridView looks like in HTML rowspan,
meaning one cell in a column covers many cells in the other column?

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to Merge DataGridView Cell in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms) (assuming you're using WinForms; if not, please [edit] the question and use the appropriate tag).

Comment: You can create a custom DataGridView Column : https://www.codemag.com/article/0707061/Create-a-Custom-DataGridView-Column